# Store the value of selection from dropdown to a variable AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-scope

I would like to store the value of a selection from a dropdown in AngularJS.

I am able to replicate the new selection on UI but not in console.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div>
    Fruit List:
    <select id="fruitsList"
        ng-model="cart"
          ng-change="getSelectedLocation()"

        ng-options="state for state in shelf"></select>
        <br/>
    <tt>Fruit selected: {{cart}}</tt>
</div>
```

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.cart = "";

  $scope.shelf = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Blueberry'];

  $scope.getSelectedLocation = function() {
    console.log($scope.cart);
  }

  $scope.printSelectedValue = function() {
    if ($scope.cart == 'Banana') {
      console.log("Its a banana")
    } else if ($scope.cart == "Apple") {
      console.log("Its an apple")
    } else {
      console.log("Its neither a banana nor an apple")
    }
  }

});
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Td2NZ/2174/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the cart once, when the controller is instanciated. At that time, the user hasn't had the chance to select anything yet.

If you want to print the selection every time it changes, use ng-change (you're already using it, BTW):

```
ng-change="printSelection()"
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.printSelection = function() {
  console.log($scope.cart);
};
```

Comment: Yeah. But how do I store that to a variable? If I select bananas, I want that to be stored to a variable and if I select apple, the new value for that variable should be "apple"

Comment: So I return $scope.cart inside the printSelection function and how do I use the selected values inside other functions?

http://jsfiddle.net/Td2NZ/2172/

Why doesnt the console print anything now?

Comment: Because you're, once again, printing abcd once, when the controller is instanciated. At that time, the user hasn't had the chance to select anything yet. Move the console.log() statement inside the getSelectedLocation function.

Comment: Yeah okay. Is there a way to return that to a variable and can use that value in any part of the controller?

Comment: You can use $scope.cart, wthout that useless abcd variable, from anywhere in the controller. You just need to understand when instructions are executed. Instructions that are directly in the controller function are executed once, when the controller is instanciated.

Comment: Thanks JB. Sorry to bug you, but a last doubt. ng-change is a function and the value of $scope.cart will be present just inside that particular function right? WIll the selected value be available to the whole controller or just for using that inside the function?

Comment: Please have a look at this. This is what I am trying to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/Td2NZ/2174/

Comment: The $scope is available anywhere in the controller. Just call your function after you've made a selection (for example, when clicking on a button), and you'll see: http://jsfiddle.net/h94gfc8p/1/